# multiple signup form when using django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I want to customize my signup form and bring a new feature. The new feature is a signup form with two category. One is signup as a developer which will have one more field called experties and another a general signup which will have username, email, password and confirm password. I have done the general signup process but no idea on best way to handle another signup form. And they will be shown on the same page.

[image]

Signup form as a general user that i could do is

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'pages.custom_sign_up_form.CustomSignupForm'
```

custom_sign_up_form.py

```
class CustomSignupForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        if settings.INVITE_MODE:
            invitation, _ = Invitation.objects.get_or_create(email=email)
            if not invitation.request_approved:
                self.add_error('email', 'Sorry at this time you are not invited. But we have added you to our invite list')
        return email

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.save()
```

**signup.html**

```
<form class="ui form login" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="field">
            {% if form.username.errors %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input error" data-tooltip="{{form.name.errors.0}}" data-position="right center">
            {% else %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input">
            {% endif %}
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="user icon"></i>
              <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control-ui" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            {% if form.email.errors %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input error" data-tooltip="{{form.email.errors.0}}" data-position="right center">
                      {% else %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input">
            {% endif %}
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="user icon"></i>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control-ui" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            {% if form.password1.errors %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input error" data-tooltip="{{form.password1.errors.0}}" data-position="right center">
            {% else %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input">
            {% endif %}
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="asterisk icon"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password1" class="form-control-ui" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            {% if form.password2.errors %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input error" data-tooltip="{{form.password2.errors.0}}" data-position="right center">
            {% else %}
              <div class="ui big left icon input">
            {% endif %}
              <i aria-hidden="true" class="asterisk icon"></i>
              <input type="password" name="password2" class="form-control-ui" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            {% if redirect_field_value %}
            <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="ui big fluid button primary">Signup</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: There are two alternative solutions given here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44505242/multiple-user-type-sign-up-with-django-allauth/45934856#45934856